# How to merge the unallocated space to c drive in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to merge the unallocated space in my system in c drive without using any third-party app. C: drive does not show any `Extend volume` Option as shown in fig[image]

How to add this unallocated space to C: drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Windows tools allow you to extend a volume only if you have contiguous free space next to the it.

There are additional constraints depending the type of volume (basic vs dynamic for example). Third-party tools can help you satisfy these constraints by forcefully reallocating the offending blocks in such a way free space is then available when needed.

If the option does not show, usually, it is a sign that no free space is available.

Answer (score -1):

if at all the unallocated space is not near the disk C, one has to use third party applications to partition though they are paid for example some links of third party applications are below;

https://www.diskpart.com/download-home.html